# How can I find the users that queried a view in Redshift?

Tags: sql, view, amazon-redshift, usage-statistics

Hello everyone and thank you in advanced!

I'm having trouble to find a query to get a list of users that have queried some specifics ***views***.
A example to clarify, if I have a couple of views

**user_activity_last_6_months** &

**user_compliance_last_month**

I need to know who is querying those 2 views and if posible other statistics. This could be a desired output.

```
+--------+-----------------------------+----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------+-------------------+----------------------+------------------+
| userid |          view_name          | queryid  |         starttime          |          endtime           | query_cpu_time | query_blocks_read | query_execution_time | return_row_count |
+--------+-----------------------------+----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------+-------------------+----------------------+------------------+
|    293 | user_activity_last_6_months | 88723456 | 2018-05-08 13:08:08.727686 | 2018-05-08 13:08:12.423532 |              4 |              1023 |                    6 |              435 |
|    345 | user_compliance_last_month  | 99347882 | 2018-05-10 00:00:03.049967 | 2018-05-10 00:00:09.177362 |              6 |               345 |                    8 |              214 |
|    345 | user_activity_last_6_months | 99347883 | 2018-05-10 12:27:36.637483 | 2018-05-10 12:27:44.502705 |              8 |                14 |                    9 |               13 |
|    293 | user_compliance_last_month  | 99347884 | 2018-05-10 12:31:00.433556 | 2018-05-10 12:31:30.090183 |             30 |                67 |                   35 |             7654 |
+--------+-----------------------------+----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------+-------------------+----------------------+------------------+
```

I have developed a query to get this info but for tables in the database using system tables and views, but I can't find any clue to get the same results for views.

As I've said, the first 3 columns are mandatory and the others will be nice to have. Plus, any further information is welcome!!

Thank you all!!

Comment: You might have to parse the information from the `STL_QUERY` and `STL_QUERYTEXT` tables. I don't think there's a convenient list of tables/views accessed.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm trying to avoid right now. But it seems it is the only way :(

Answer (score 4):

If you need that level of auditing for table and view access then I recommend you start by enabling [Database Audit Logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/db-auditing.html) for your Redshift cluster. This will generate a number of logs files in S3.

The "User Activity Log" contains the text for all queries run on the cluster, it can then either be loaded back into Redshift or [added as a Spectrum table](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyze-database-audit-logs-for-security-and-compliance-using-amazon-redshift-spectrum/) so that the query text can be parsed for table and view names.

Comment: Thank you [Nathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46239/nathan) for the answer. I was looking for a more direct way to resolve this question but it seems to be there's no other way more than parse querys for view names. If I get to solve it this way I'll let you know.